# Unable to run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody help me about this problem... Actually the rails console gets crash in windows command prompt... i can able to run the sample application server but unable to run this rails console...Please and Please Help me... Thanks in Advance..

The error is

Looks like your app's `./bin/rails` is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's `bin/` directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

```
  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control
```

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

```
  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable


WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activa
ted activesupport 4.0.0.rc1, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.2.8. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::Load
Error)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from D:/Rasool_Projects/Project_4/sample_app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:42:in `block in exec_a
pp_rails'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `exec_app_rails'

        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/cli.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Start using RVM. Put your gems for a project in a separate gemset or just create a .rvmrc. You will never run into such issues.

However, I was once struck with same error and uninstalling the gem and reinstalling it manually worked for me.

Uninstall a gem:

```
gem uninstall <gem_name>
```

It will prompt for the version to remove if there are multiple versions of that gem on your system.

Then, Install a gem:

```
gem install <gem_name_with_version>
```

Comment: @ user1541507 ... Thanks for your Help... by uninstalling entire rails and then re installing solved my problem... Thank you.. :)

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. Upvoted because this works.

Answer (score 0):

This warning says : `You have already activa
ted activesupport 4.0.0.rc1, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.2.8. Using bundle exec may solve this`

You just have to update rails `gem update rails` to install dependencies activesupport, etc.

Before update your Gemfile, delete `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: To hypee..Thank you so much for reply., i tried both the options..but it shows the same repeated error.. is there any other suggestion..please

Comment: put `gem list` in your terminal and check activerecord, activesupport, etc have a 4.0.0 version installed. Delete your Gemfile.lock and put `bundle update`

Comment: there is nothing 4.0.0 version related gem in my gemlist and even i tried this bundle update.. no use... :(

Comment: If you do not find in the list is that they are not installed `gem install rails --version=4.0.0.rc1`

Comment: @ hypee ... Thanks for your Help... by uninstalling entire rails and reinstaling solved my problem... Thank you.. :)